# Hazelcast cluster update nodes

Tags: updates, hazelcast

I'm trying to find out if and how Hazelcast manages version-updates of nodes in a cluster. I found this:

[Support Hazelcast update in running cluster](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14)

It seems to be possible just with minor version updates... 
Has someone experienced updating a Hazelcast Cluster? What should I do if I want to update a major version change?
I wasn't able to find something about updating cluster nodes in the Hazelcast documentation...

Thanks for any help,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way is to totally shut down the cluster, replace the jars and restart. Rolling upgrade is on the agenda.